# Spring Boot - configurable beans

Tags: spring, spring-boot

How can I load my spring beans from an external XML file?

Example xml:

```
<bean class="com.mycompany.Config">
    <property name="targets">
        <list>
            <bean class="com.mycompany.Target">
                <property name="url">http://bla</property>
                <property name="authentication">
                    <bean class="com.mycompany.Auth">
                        <property name="type" value="basic"/>
                        <property name="user" value="user1"/>
                        <property name="pass" value="asdf"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
            <bean class="com.mycompany.Target">
                <property name="url">http://otherbla</property>
                <property name="authentication">
                    <bean class="com.mycompany.Auth">
                        <property name="type" value="basic"/>
                        <property name="user" value="user2"/>
                        <property name="pass" value="start123"/>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
            [as many Target beans as I want]
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Spring Boot:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.mycompany"})
@ImportResource({"file:config/config.xml"})
public class Application {

    /**
     * Spring Boot Startpoint.
     *
     * @param args Commandline arguments
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I tried different ways but none worked. If I include the xml in my jar I have no idea how I can overwrite it externally OUTSIDE the jar. Otherwise the tests cant start the context. How should I set `@ImportResource({"file:config/config.xml"})` so the app can find the xml AND all tests pass?

I need to externally configure the Target bean.

Comment: try `@ImportResource({"classpath*:config/config.xml"})`. Where is this config folder ? under resources?

Comment: @pvpkiran the config folder is the config folder of spring boot where application.properties is. with "classpath" the file on the filesystem is NOT loaded nor does it overwrite the one in the JAR ...

Answer (score 0):

As I haven't found an answer I came up with following idea:

One `@Configuration` class in my main classes with `@Profile("default")` and `@ImportResource("file:/config/beans.xml")` and another `@Configuration` class in my test classes with  with `@Profile("!default")` and `@ImportResource("classpath*:test-beans.xml")`.

Full POC see https://gitlab.com/Sheldor5/configurable-spring-boot-sample